# jQuery .on multiple events and selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-on

Currently, I have a cached variable, `$this`, on which I'm applying `.on` to respond to various possible types of behaviour triggers.

```
$this.on('click','.trigger a',rowTrigger);
$this.on('click','.actions nav a',rowAction);
```

In the [jQuery .on Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) it doesn't mention if there's a way to combine the above two into a single call.  For example, something like this might be nice:

```
$this.onAny({
    click: [
        {'.trigger a':rowTrigger},
        {'.actions nav a':rowAction}
    ]
});
```

Is there a way to achieve this kind of statement (e.g. an existing plugin to extend `.on`)?

**UPDATE**

Use Case (in the current code, prior to a nice solution):

```
// Plugin 1:
function addTriggers(){
  $this.find('td:last').append('<span class="trigger"><a href="#"></a></span>');
  return {selector:'.trigger a', event:'click', target: $this, callback: rowTrigger};
}

// Plugin 2:
function addInlineNavigation(){
  $navCode = '...'
  $this.find('td:last').append('<div class="actions">'+$navCode.html()+'</div>');
  return {selector:'.actions nav a', event:'click', target: $this, callback: rowAction};
}
```

Comment: To create an array that can be added to by other plugins that want to extend functionality to `$this` when certain events are bound (in my case). An object would also work, but the idea I'm working with is to abstract out the target selector and callback pairs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462027/jquery-on-method-on-multiple-selectors

Comment: This SO reference refers to multiple selectors with a single callback, not multiple selectors with multiple callbacks, but thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a way to achieve this kind of statement (e.g. an existing plugin to extend `.on`)?

I'm not aware of one. Would be nearly trivial to write. I'm not seeing much advantage to it, though, compared with chaining:

```
$this.on('click','.trigger a',rowTrigger)
     .on('click','.actions nav a',rowAction);
```

But again, the plug-in isn't complicated. Here's an untested rough draft:

```
jQuery.fn.onAny = function(options) {
    var eventName, eventSpec, eventEntry, selector, i;

    for (eventName in options) {
        eventSpec = options[eventName];
        if (jQuery.isArray(eventSpec)) {
            // Your example, where each event name has an array of objects
            // keyed by selector, where the value is the handler
            for (i = 0; i < eventSpec.length; ++i) {
                eventEntry = eventSpec[i];
                for (selector in eventEntry) {
                    this.on(eventName, selector, eventEntry[selector]);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            // Assuming just a straight handler here
            this.on(eventName, eventSpec);
        }
    }

    return this;
};
```

Comment: +1 for "I'm not seeing much advantage to it" and the chained call. Building a plugin for this is IMO a bad idea. New team members would have to learn what it is etc.

Comment: Hi =) the area where I'm applying this is documented, so this would be a simple thing to learn.  E.g. in my case I have an array holding event names (e.g. 'click'), a selector to listen to (e.g. '.trigger a') and the callback (rowTrigger) function name. It functions like pub/sub in some ways, so it's not a steep learning curve, but useful in my particular case!

Comment: @TimBüthe: Thanks for fixing that typo!

Comment: @MyStream: do you really need this in more than one place? If not, just iterate your array and attach the handlers using 'on'. If you need it more than once, write a utility function. And if you need it all over the place, make a plugin or refactor your code :-)

Comment: I have different functions for admin, account and public areas of a site I'm working on so I was looking to generalise the logic of adding event handlers to a common function or plugin instead of duplicating the logic inline in each file.  It's not essential, just wondering and T.J. Crowder's method allows me to write `$( selector ).onAny( behaviourEnhancements );` which is an elegant solution, I think, for this use-case? The code's quite short, but I was 50/50 on making a plugin so thought I'd ask better minds first :)