# Jquery remove background color on first and last rows in a table

Tags: jquery, css, click, background-color

I am trying to remove background color on click for tables first and last rows. I am trying in the below way. Any optimized way to handle this so that I can call only one time?

```
//Except First row
 $('#tblNames').on('click', 'tr:not(:first-child)', function () {
        var state = $(this).hasClass('highlighted');
        $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
        if (!state) { $(this).addClass('highlighted'); }
    });

//Except Last row
 $('#tblNames').on('click', 'tr:not(:last-child)', function () {
        var state = $(this).hasClass('highlighted');
        $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
        if (!state) { $(this).addClass('highlighted'); }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $('#tblNames').on('click', 'tr:not(:first-child), tr:not(:last-child)', function () {
        var state = $(this).hasClass('highlighted');
        $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
        if (!state) { $(this).addClass('highlighted'); }
    });
```

Source for the answer: [jQuery on() method on multiple selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462027/jquery-on-method-on-multiple-selectors)