# Displaying parents() as html in the navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of button elements on my page, and on `mouseover`, I want to grab the ancestors of the selected button, and then display them as either html or an array **inside the navbar**. Here is my javascript so far and it doesn't work at all. Any ideas?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("*").on.("mouseover", function() {
      var treeTraversal = $(this).parents().map(function(){
      return this.tagName;}).get().join(", ");
      $("<span>").after("<h2>" + treeTraversal + "<h2>");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the period after `on`

http://codepen.io/tmorrow-hyphensolutions/pen/JYVLdz

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("*").on("mouseover", function() {
        var treeTraversal = $(this).parents().map(function() {
          return this.tagName;
        }).get().join(", ");
        alert(treeTraversal);
        $("<span>").after("<h2>" + treeTraversal + "<h2>");
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="srg">
  <div class="g">
    <!--m-->
    <div class="rc" data-hveid="28">
      <h3 class="r"><a href="http://api.jquery.com/on/" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','AFQjCNFJf1Y9q7iSptlkW-9S_Ki4f0hD8w','NhJPBzK8gcIkyyzrmFjnDg','0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQFggdMAA','','',event)" target="_blank">.on() | jQuery API Documentation</a></h3>
      <div class="s">
        <div>
          <div class="f kv _SWb" style="white-space:nowrap"><cite class="_Rm bc">api.jquery.com › Events › Event Handler Attachment</cite>
            <div class="action-menu ab_ctl">
              <a class="_Fmb ab_button" href="#" id="am-b0" aria-label="Result details" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" jsaction="m.tdd;keydown:m.hbke;keypress:m.mskpe" data-ved="0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQ7B0IHzAA"><span class="mn-dwn-arw"></span>
              </a>
              <div class="action-menu-panel ab_dropdown" role="menu" tabindex="-1" jsaction="keydown:m.hdke;mouseover:m.hdhne;mouseout:m.hdhue" data-ved="0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQqR8IIDAA">
                <ul>
                  <li class="action-menu-item ab_dropdownitem" role="menuitem"><a class="fl" href="http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:8rVcz6sYu0cJ:api.jquery.com/on/+&amp;cd=1&amp;hl=en&amp;ct=clnk&amp;gl=us" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','AFQjCNFRzU6U8v-SD-acmExsnmywuvXzbA','C2O6G-mvsEfY1SSmHzNwjg','0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQIAghMAA','','',event)"
                    target="_blank">Cached</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="action-menu-item ab_dropdownitem" role="menuitem"><a class="fl" href="/search?newwindow=1&amp;safe=active&amp;espv=2&amp;biw=1920&amp;bih=955&amp;q=related:api.jquery.com/on/+jquery+on&amp;tbo=1&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQHwgiMAA">Similar</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="crc">
              <div class="crl" data-async-context="res:0;ri:;site:api.jquery.com" data-async-trigger="cra-0-filled" jsaction="crd.tglpop" data-ved="0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQ5CsIIzAA">jQuery<span class="_Bs"></span>
              </div>
              <div class="cri" jsaction="crd.popclk">
                <div id="cra-0-filled" data-jiis="up" data-async-type="cra" data-async-context-required="site,ri,res" class="y yp" jsaction="asyncFilled:crd.rmload"></div>
                <div class="cr-load">Loading...</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div><span class="st">The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the <em>jQuery</em> object. As of <em>jQuery</em> 1.7, the .on() method provides all&nbsp;...</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--n-->
  </div>
  <div class="g">
    <!--m-->
    <div class="rc" data-hveid="36">
      <h3 class="r"><a href="http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_on.asp" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','2','AFQjCNH44PiKdeqPZjPI21kJePxn9iVL1w','5PIhxQOkdnFLzIjo3gdhvw','0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQFgglMAE','','',event)" target="_blank">jQuery on() Method - W3Schools</a></h3>
      <div class="s">
        <div>
          <div class="f kv _SWb" style="white-space:nowrap"><cite class="_Rm">www.w3schools.com/<b>jquery</b>/event_on.asp</cite>
            <div class="action-menu ab_ctl">
              <a class="_Fmb ab_button" href="#" id="am-b1" aria-label="Result details" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" jsaction="m.tdd;keydown:m.hbke;keypress:m.mskpe" data-ved="0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQ7B0IJjAB"><span class="mn-dwn-arw"></span>
              </a>
              <div class="action-menu-panel ab_dropdown" role="menu" tabindex="-1" jsaction="keydown:m.hdke;mouseover:m.hdhne;mouseout:m.hdhue" data-ved="0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQqR8IJzAB">
                <ul>
                  <li class="action-menu-item ab_dropdownitem" role="menuitem"><a class="fl" href="http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:YTIHxjS-2WAJ:www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_on.asp+&amp;cd=2&amp;hl=en&amp;ct=clnk&amp;gl=us" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','2','AFQjCNG6qo34j9mEX_qelzFDnT0CI1EYzA','mL8lsXUzoXj-j35I3pSWvQ','0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQIAgoMAE','','',event)"
                    target="_blank">Cached</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="action-menu-item ab_dropdownitem" role="menuitem"><a class="fl" href="/search?newwindow=1&amp;safe=active&amp;espv=2&amp;biw=1920&amp;bih=955&amp;q=related:www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_on.asp+jquery+on&amp;tbo=1&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQHwgpMAE">Similar</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="crc">
              <div class="crl" data-async-context="res:1;ri:;site:w3schools.com" data-async-trigger="cra-1-filled" jsaction="crd.tglpop" data-ved="0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQ5CsIKjAB">W3Schools<span class="_Bs"></span>
              </div>
              <div class="cri" jsaction="crd.popclk">
                <div id="cra-1-filled" data-jiis="up" data-async-type="cra" data-async-context-required="site,ri,res" class="y yp" jsaction="asyncFilled:crd.rmload"></div>
                <div class="cr-load">Loading...</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div><span class="st">As of <em>jQuery</em> version 1.7, the on() method is the new replacement for the bind(), live() and delegate() methods. This method brings a lot of consistency to the API,<wbr>&nbsp;...</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--n-->
  </div>
  <div class="g">
    <!--m-->
    <div class="rc" data-hveid="43">
      <h3 class="r"><a href="http://www.andismith.com/blog/2011/11/on-and-off/" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','3','AFQjCNGZOdfVh2BXopsozHWYJLMiHaFi4g','BGdFVXWwMyTLkZQ8wAo1bw','0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQFggsMAI','','',event)" target="_blank">Using jQuery .on() and .off() - Andi Smith</a></h3>
      <div class="s">
        <div>
          <div class="f kv _SWb" style="white-space:nowrap"><cite class="_Rm">www.andismith.com/blog/2011/11/on-and-off/</cite>
            <div class="action-menu ab_ctl">
              <a class="_Fmb ab_button" href="#" id="am-b2" aria-label="Result details" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" jsaction="m.tdd;keydown:m.hbke;keypress:m.mskpe" data-ved="0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQ7B0ILTAC"><span class="mn-dwn-arw"></span>
              </a>
              <div class="action-menu-panel ab_dropdown" role="menu" tabindex="-1" jsaction="keydown:m.hdke;mouseover:m.hdhne;mouseout:m.hdhue" data-ved="0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQqR8ILjAC">
                <ul>
                  <li class="action-menu-item ab_dropdownitem" role="menuitem"><a class="fl" href="http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:y-hA0v9zG8wJ:www.andismith.com/blog/2011/11/on-and-off/+&amp;cd=3&amp;hl=en&amp;ct=clnk&amp;gl=us" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','3','AFQjCNGncjEU5RN4W85c35ZU2_fJh5sqYw','dZ2BeFUUkajUbBaKUUKCvQ','0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQIAgvMAI','','',event)"
                    target="_blank">Cached</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="action-menu-item ab_dropdownitem" role="menuitem"><a class="fl" href="/search?newwindow=1&amp;safe=active&amp;espv=2&amp;biw=1920&amp;bih=955&amp;q=related:www.andismith.com/blog/2011/11/on-and-off/+jquery+on&amp;tbo=1&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQHwgwMAI">Similar</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div><span class="st"><span class="f">Nov 10, 2011 - </span>With the release of <em>jQuery</em> 1.7 on November 3rd came two new ways to attach event handlers - .on() and .off() . Whilst possibly not the most&nbsp;...</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--n-->
  </div>
  <div class="g">
    <!--m-->
    <div class="rc" data-hveid="50">
      <h3 class="r"><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','4','AFQjCNGwAbe5yxKciYpf1HmvVSHJD2wyfA','H2pKTCHI1e3Kswt0qino0Q','0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQFggzMAM','','',event)" target="_blank">javascript - Direct vs. Delegated - jQuery .on() - Stack Overflow</a></h3>
      <div class="s">
        <div>
          <div class="f kv _SWb" style="white-space:nowrap"><cite class="_Rm">stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-<b>jquery-on</b></cite>
            <div class="action-menu ab_ctl">
              <a class="_Fmb ab_button" href="#" id="am-b3" aria-label="Result details" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" jsaction="m.tdd;keydown:m.hbke;keypress:m.mskpe" data-ved="0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQ7B0INDAD"><span class="mn-dwn-arw"></span>
              </a>
              <div class="action-menu-panel ab_dropdown" role="menu" tabindex="-1" jsaction="keydown:m.hdke;mouseover:m.hdhne;mouseout:m.hdhue" data-ved="0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQqR8INTAD">
                <ul>
                  <li class="action-menu-item ab_dropdownitem" role="menuitem"><a class="fl" href="http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:kfKCB8W6O08J:stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on+&amp;cd=4&amp;hl=en&amp;ct=clnk&amp;gl=us" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','4','AFQjCNH8XPlE4fUW33d7b96W02J65CKYxA','XvltZ34CXmgq8BRMkOtdRw','0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQIAg2MAM','','',event)"
                    target="_blank">Cached</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="action-menu-item ab_dropdownitem" role="menuitem"><a class="fl" href="/search?newwindow=1&amp;safe=active&amp;espv=2&amp;biw=1920&amp;bih=955&amp;q=related:stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on+jquery+on&amp;tbo=1&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQHwg3MAM">Similar</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div><span class="st"><span class="f">Nov 13, 2011 - </span>I am trying to understand this particular difference between the direct ... Case 1 (
          <wbr>direct): $("div#target span.green").on("click", function() {...});.</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--n-->
  </div>
  <div class="g">
    <!--m-->
    <div class="rc" data-hveid="57">
      <h3 class="r"><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608145/jquery-on-method-with-multiple-event-handlers-to-one-selector" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','5','AFQjCNG3A5QbaTby2LssEhuWZsYABzMY1Q','Cc9hq3o0t2AA5tXi-OmOTA','0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQFgg6MAQ','','',event)" target="_blank">javascript - JQuery .on() method with multiple event ...</a></h3>
      <div class="s">
        <div>
          <div class="f kv _SWb" style="white-space:nowrap"><cite class="_Rm">stackoverflow.com/.../<b>jquery-on</b>-method-with-multiple-event-handlers-to...</cite>
            <div class="action-menu ab_ctl">
              <a class="_Fmb ab_button" href="#" id="am-b4" aria-label="Result details" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" jsaction="m.tdd;keydown:m.hbke;keypress:m.mskpe" data-ved="0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQ7B0IOzAE"><span class="mn-dwn-arw"></span>
              </a>
              <div class="action-menu-panel ab_dropdown" role="menu" tabindex="-1" jsaction="keydown:m.hdke;mouseover:m.hdhne;mouseout:m.hdhue" data-ved="0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQqR8IPDAE">
                <ul>
                  <li class="action-menu-item ab_dropdownitem" role="menuitem"><a class="fl" href="http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:1nvmIzHsJ4YJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/8608145/jquery-on-method-with-multiple-event-handlers-to-one-selector+&amp;cd=5&amp;hl=en&amp;ct=clnk&amp;gl=us" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','5','AFQjCNGsUSw1q47GclaT0-xw9gQ7Nn8tDw','FrhwVViTTrHsR0p9X5Z3Fw','0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQIAg9MAQ','','',event)"
                    target="_blank">Cached</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="action-menu-item ab_dropdownitem" role="menuitem"><a class="fl" href="/search?newwindow=1&amp;safe=active&amp;espv=2&amp;biw=1920&amp;bih=955&amp;q=related:stackoverflow.com/questions/8608145/jquery-on-method-with-multiple-event-handlers-to-one-selector+jquery+on&amp;tbo=1&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQHwg-MAQ">Similar</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div><span class="st"><span class="f">Dec 22, 2011 - </span>That's the other way around. You should write: $("table.planning_grid").on({ mouseenter: function() { // Handle mouseenter... }, mouseleave: function()&nbsp;...</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--n-->
  </div>
  <div class="g">
    <!--m-->
    <div class="rc" data-hveid="64">
      <h3 class="r"><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462027/jquery-on-method-on-multiple-selectors" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','6','AFQjCNHbozVSbvA7zGVoSaz3WQXtRYW6gw','2FMXRhPAaTmfi8-mhMdpAg','0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQFghBMAU','','',event)" target="_blank">jQuery on() method on multiple selectors - Stack Overflow</a></h3>
      <div class="s">
        <div>
          <div class="f kv _SWb" style="white-space:nowrap"><cite class="_Rm">stackoverflow.com/questions/.../<b>jquery-on</b>-method-on-multiple-selectors</cite>
            <div class="action-menu ab_ctl">
              <a class="_Fmb ab_button" href="#" id="am-b5" aria-label="Result details" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" jsaction="m.tdd;keydown:m.hbke;keypress:m.mskpe" data-ved="0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQ7B0IQjAF"><span class="mn-dwn-arw"></span>
              </a>
              <div class="action-menu-panel ab_dropdown" role="menu" tabindex="-1" jsaction="keydown:m.hdke;mouseover:m.hdhne;mouseout:m.hdhue" data-ved="0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQqR8IQzAF">
                <ul>
                  <li class="action-menu-item ab_dropdownitem" role="menuitem"><a class="fl" href="http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:5P_KmFYLMBYJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/8462027/jquery-on-method-on-multiple-selectors+&amp;cd=6&amp;hl=en&amp;ct=clnk&amp;gl=us" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','6','AFQjCNFTBFtIVBHMibxxiq4TackeqipWTA','Ntr2K6L1CllzCb8bwXGPuA','0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQIAhEMAU','','',event)"
                    target="_blank">Cached</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="action-menu-item ab_dropdownitem" role="menuitem"><a class="fl" href="/search?newwindow=1&amp;safe=active&amp;espv=2&amp;biw=1920&amp;bih=955&amp;q=related:stackoverflow.com/questions/8462027/jquery-on-method-on-multiple-selectors+jquery+on&amp;tbo=1&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQHwhFMAU">Similar</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div><span class="st"><span class="f">Dec 11, 2011 - </span>If you're trying to use .on() so that you can listen to events on DOM object that may be created after you make the initial .on() call, then the most&nbsp;...</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--n-->
  </div>
  <div class="g">
    <!--m-->
    <div class="rc" data-hveid="71">
      <h3 class="r"><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090942/jquery-event-handler-not-working-on-dynamic-content" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','7','AFQjCNGQRJeFz4pJKr-WYeQSgKeOp3qanA','rpzJCLxlbpzbbYUGna-BUw','0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQFghIMAY','','',event)" target="_blank">Jquery event handler not working on dynamic content ...</a></h3>
      <div class="s">
        <div>
          <div class="f kv _SWb" style="white-space:nowrap"><cite class="_Rm">stackoverflow.com/.../<b>jquery</b>-event-handler-not-working-on-dynamic-co...</cite>
            <div class="action-menu ab_ctl">
              <a class="_Fmb ab_button" href="#" id="am-b6" aria-label="Result details" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" jsaction="m.tdd;keydown:m.hbke;keypress:m.mskpe" data-ved="0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQ7B0ISTAG"><span class="mn-dwn-arw"></span>
              </a>
              <div class="action-menu-panel ab_dropdown" role="menu" tabindex="-1" jsaction="keydown:m.hdke;mouseover:m.hdhne;mouseout:m.hdhue" data-ved="0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQqR8ISjAG">
                <ul>
                  <li class="action-menu-item ab_dropdownitem" role="menuitem"><a class="fl" href="http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:HlLIHpXKQ7IJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/15090942/jquery-event-handler-not-working-on-dynamic-content+&amp;cd=7&amp;hl=en&amp;ct=clnk&amp;gl=us" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','7','AFQjCNFXOX_k1de1jqHnBCf2TgKrIsWPxg','KdRnXJmU0-WqAU1NWZ1wWQ','0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQIAhLMAY','','',event)"
                    target="_blank">Cached</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div><span class="st"><span class="f">Feb 26, 2013 - </span>You have to add the selector parameter, otherwise the event is directly bound instead of delegated, which only works if the element already exists (so&nbsp;...</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--n-->
  </div>
  <div class="g">
    <!--m-->
    <div class="rc" data-hveid="77">
      <h3 class="r"><a href="http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Jun/12/Replacing-jQuerylive-with-jQueryon" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','8','AFQjCNH2aoWYimIJBcRriJDzF-xrGyrOJQ','eWz8cz8Vh6RE4Vy2lVqm6w','0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQFghOMAc','','',event)" target="_blank">Replacing jQuery.live() with jQuery.on() - Rick Strahl's Web ...</a></h3>
      <div class="s">
        <div>
          <div class="f kv _SWb" style="white-space:nowrap"><cite class="_Rm">weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/.../Replacing-<b>jQuery</b>live-with-<b>jQuery</b>...</cite>
            <div class="action-menu ab_ctl">
              <a class="_Fmb ab_button" href="#" id="am-b7" aria-label="Result details" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" jsaction="m.tdd;keydown:m.hbke;keypress:m.mskpe" data-ved="0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQ7B0ITzAH"><span class="mn-dwn-arw"></span>
              </a>
              <div class="action-menu-panel ab_dropdown" role="menu" tabindex="-1" jsaction="keydown:m.hdke;mouseover:m.hdhne;mouseout:m.hdhue" data-ved="0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQqR8IUDAH">
                <ul>
                  <li class="action-menu-item ab_dropdownitem" role="menuitem"><a class="fl" href="http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:0lmueC_HH1AJ:weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Jun/12/Replacing-jQuerylive-with-jQueryon+&amp;cd=8&amp;hl=en&amp;ct=clnk&amp;gl=us" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','8','AFQjCNEme9STE-hmv97uiK8edaCxAAK8og','b1TBIijjmTlAvZJsiFFxyw','0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQIAhRMAc','','',event)"
                    target="_blank">Cached</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="action-menu-item ab_dropdownitem" role="menuitem"><a class="fl" href="/search?newwindow=1&amp;safe=active&amp;espv=2&amp;biw=1920&amp;bih=955&amp;q=related:weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Jun/12/Replacing-jQuerylive-with-jQueryon+jquery+on&amp;tbo=1&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQHwhSMAc">Similar</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div><span class="st"><span class="f">Jun 12, 2013 - </span>In <em>jQuery</em> 1.9 and later the <em>jQuery</em>.live() function has finally been removed which has caused me a bit of upgrade trouble. While <em>jQuery</em>.live() has&nbsp;...</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--n-->
  </div>
  <div class="g">
    <!--m-->
    <div class="rc" data-hveid="84">
      <h3 class="r"><a href="https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/51205802e1738f7cce000002" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','9','AFQjCNHKIeuhWKwOsU9XATx7ak997qhmeg','KdfKRvXAJgFNy_XWRevKKw','0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQFghVMAg','','',event)" target="_blank">How to run jquery on local machine | Codecademy</a></h3>
      <div class="s">
        <div>
          <div class="f kv _SWb" style="white-space:nowrap"><cite class="_Rm">https://www.codecademy.com/.../51205802e1738f7cce000...</cite>
            <div class="action-menu ab_ctl">
              <a class="_Fmb ab_button" href="#" id="am-b8" aria-label="Result details" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" jsaction="m.tdd;keydown:m.hbke;keypress:m.mskpe" data-ved="0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQ7B0IVjAI"><span class="mn-dwn-arw"></span>
              </a>
              <div class="action-menu-panel ab_dropdown" role="menu" tabindex="-1" jsaction="keydown:m.hdke;mouseover:m.hdhne;mouseout:m.hdhue" data-ved="0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQqR8IVzAI">
                <ul>
                  <li class="action-menu-item ab_dropdownitem" role="menuitem"><a class="fl" href="http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:3art-hmBPRIJ:https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/51205802e1738f7cce000002+&amp;cd=9&amp;hl=en&amp;ct=clnk&amp;gl=us" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','9','AFQjCNGiEWjfeOL5RBvSIyVsg-lDMMrU8g','YqfskRg-sa91JCIncDiz1w','0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQIAhYMAg','','',event)"
                    target="_blank">Cached</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="crc">
              <div class="crl" data-async-context="res:8;ri:;site:codecademy.com" data-async-trigger="cra-8-filled" jsaction="crd.tglpop" data-ved="0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQ5CsIWTAI">Codecademy<span class="_Bs"></span>
              </div>
              <div class="cri" jsaction="crd.popclk">
                <div id="cra-8-filled" data-jiis="up" data-async-type="cra" data-async-context-required="site,ri,res" class="y yp" jsaction="asyncFilled:crd.rmload"></div>
                <div class="cr-load">Loading...</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div><span class="st">I'm trying to move all this code to my local machine, but I cannot get the script.js to run. I put the HTML, CSS, and JS in the same folder, and it looks like the HTML&nbsp;...</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--n-->
  </div>
  <div class="g">
    <!--m-->
    <div class="rc" data-hveid="90">
      <h3 class="r"><a href="https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/55be6dd5d3292f851a00067c" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','10','AFQjCNFS1Z_TSMznAYbCtapBeisdAsWmuA','wm1RcWplcb6J_e6PXz9Xww','0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQFghbMAk','','',event)" target="_blank">one of function in jQuery .on() | Codecademy</a></h3>
      <div class="s">
        <div>
          <div class="f kv _SWb" style="white-space:nowrap"><cite class="_Rm">https://www.codecademy.com/.../55be6dd5d3292f851a000...</cite>
            <div class="action-menu ab_ctl">
              <a class="_Fmb ab_button" href="#" id="am-b9" aria-label="Result details" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" jsaction="m.tdd;keydown:m.hbke;keypress:m.mskpe" data-ved="0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQ7B0IXDAJ"><span class="mn-dwn-arw"></span>
              </a>
              <div class="action-menu-panel ab_dropdown" role="menu" tabindex="-1" jsaction="keydown:m.hdke;mouseover:m.hdhne;mouseout:m.hdhue" data-ved="0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQqR8IXTAJ">
                <ul>
                  <li class="action-menu-item ab_dropdownitem" role="menuitem"><a class="fl" href="http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:l4osBjpDoeoJ:https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/55be6dd5d3292f851a00067c+&amp;cd=10&amp;hl=en&amp;ct=clnk&amp;gl=us" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','10','AFQjCNH1_jjMjre3YXyAKeuaBANXAJU00w','DTLCB08h3zoDEpPplWsvDA','0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQIAheMAk','','',event)"
                    target="_blank">Cached</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="crc">
              <div class="crl" data-async-context="res:9;ri:;site:codecademy.com" data-async-trigger="cra-9-filled" jsaction="crd.tglpop" data-ved="0ahUKEwjxka_JkKLJAhWFHT4KHbPJCYUQ5CsIXzAJ">Codecademy<span class="_Bs"></span>
              </div>
              <div class="cri" jsaction="crd.popclk">
                <div id="cra-9-filled" data-jiis="up" data-async-type="cra" data-async-context-required="site,ri,res" class="y yp" jsaction="asyncFilled:crd.rmload"></div>
                <div class="cr-load">Loading...</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div><span class="st">Can someone explain what ".on()" it is and how it works in <em>jQuery</em>? The explanation on preview on 13/14 Modifying HTML Elements, I do not really understand it&nbsp;...</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--n-->
  </div>
</div>
```